# Whats up with cross site Scripting (getJSON) and flickr example

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

In past i had read the documentation about getJSON and there is an example with a flickr photo api.
(the example with the [pussy]cats :-)).

No I ask myself why is it possible, to access flickr directly with this example.
Ive tried this by store this code on my local machine - it works but if I use a local copy of jquery i just get an error in firebug like this

$ is not defined
myurl/test.html
Line 11

Does anybody of you have a solution for this paradox thing?

This is the documentation url HTTP:api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

The example isn´t also not working if I store the HTTP:code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js in my local jquery file.

I also dont understand why the request isnt´s visible in Firebug Console

Thank you in advance

Bernhard

---

**EDIT:**

I took the example from jquery and just replaced the source with the my local copy of that framework.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>img{ height: 100px; float: left; }</style>
  <script src="js/jquery/jjquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="images">

</div>
<script>$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
        function(data){
          $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
            $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
            if ( i == 3 ) return false;
          });
        });</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have your local copy of jQuery loaded *before* your javascript runs?

Comment: Can we see the HTML you're using? It sounds like jQuery is not being imported correctly. Make sure your URL in the script tag for the local copy is correct and is in HTML before you start using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course.

I took the example from jquery and just replaced the source with the my local copy of that framework.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>img{ height: 100px; float: left; }</style>
  <script src="js/jquery/jjquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="images">

</div>
<script>$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
        function(data){
          $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
            $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
            if ( i == 3 ) return false;
          });
        });</script>
</body>
</html>
```